# Configuring soap api xml

Tags: php, xml, web-services, api, soap

I want to configure an api of soap with php, following the xml is used for the api, but its not responding, please help me to recover this problem

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fram="http://framework.zend.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<fram:getCountries>
<securityInfo>
<userName>username</userName>
<password>password</password>
<agentCode>code</agentCode>
<lang>en</lang>
</securityInfo>
</fram:getCountries>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The below showing the php code I used to call xml. But I didnt get any response to my php code, but the xml is correct, I have asked to the provider they told me the xml is correct but my php code is not correct. I dont what I do to solve this problem :(

```
 <?php 
$soapUrl = "http://testapi.roombookpro.com/en/soap/index?wsdl"; // asmx URL of WSDL
$soapUser = "username";  //  username
$soapPassword = "password"; // password

// xml post structure
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fram="http://framework.zend.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <fram:getCountries>
  <securityInfo>
  <!-- You may enter the following 4 items in any order  -->
  <userName>username</userName>
  <password>password</password>
  <agentCode>agentcode</agentCode>
  <lang>en</lang>
  </securityInfo>
  </fram:getCountries>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>';   // data from the form, e.g. some ID number
$headers = array(
  "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
  "Accept: text/xml",
  "Cache-Control: no-cache",
  "Pragma: no-cache"
  "SOAPAction: http://testapi.roombookpro.com/en/soap/index#getCountries",
  "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
); //SOAPAction: your op URL

$url = $soapUrl;
// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
// converting
$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);
// convertingc to XML
$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
var_dump($parser);
echo $parser;
// user $parser to get your data out of XML response and to display it.
  ?>
```

Comment: are you getting any http error?

Comment: I dont know how to configure this

Comment: have you tried [this](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/your-first-soapui-project.html)

Comment: Yes I tried, but I didn't get the response, but the xml is correct, it have the response. But in my php is not working

Comment: share you php code then.

Comment: I have shared the php code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,your request is pointing to wsdl link below,

```
http://testapi.roombookpro.com/en/soap/index?wsdl
```

and thats why you are not getting soap response rather you getting the definitions.

you should use the following soap url to get the soap response,

```
http://testapi.roombookpro.com/en/soap/index
```

**EDIT:**
and to get the XML response (as string):

```
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

to get as SimpleXMLElement Object :

```
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns2:Soap_Model_SOAP_Location_Country') as $item)
        {
            print_r($item);
 //to access individual elements 
//        echo $item->id ;
//        echo $item ->code;
//        echo $item->name;
//        echo "\n";

        }
```

which gives array of XML objects:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => 252
    [code] => ZW
    [name] => Zimbabwe
)
```

Comment: I have changed that, but now I'm facing another problem, it showing in html not in xml.

Comment: Its not working, i have used **htmlentities()**
But now I can't take value from the xml

Comment: when i use **simplexml_load_string()** showing timezone error

Comment: what is your requirement? final output?

Comment: it's a search engine of hotel booking, i have configured this, but I cant take the values now.

Comment: can i get your personal mail id, i can explain what i need

Comment: I got the result, but which is in string format, and **simplexml_load_string()** is used for convert into the xml format, but it doesn't work in my code. I have to take values from the xml, now which is in string fromat.

Link showing current workig
[link]http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api2/
country : IN
City : DEL

Comment: can you accept a answer for this as original problem you asked is solved.

Comment: and suggest if you can create a separate question in sof mentioning that seems you need XML object rather string.

Comment: sure I'll accept this answer, but it still nothing showing in my code. :( :( 
.                     [link] www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api2 you can check through here, country and city details are above comment.

Comment: i am getting following error:Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hsphere/local/home/c338743/medhyaftravel.com/api/api2/index.php on line 113  can post your latest code (create a new question would be ideal) as it deals with different problem.

Comment: thank you, i have posted another question and full code